# How would i make this into a button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey so how can i turn this into a button in rails?

```
 <%= link_to "+Add Attachment!", :controller => "assets", :action => "new", :lesson_id => @lesson %>
```

Comment: [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)?

Comment: Why do you want to use a button? You can use css to make the link looks like a button. You can have a look at `bootstrap`, it very easy to change a link looks like a button. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons

Answer (score 1):

`<%= button_to "+ Add Attachment", ... %>`

Look into using the RESTful routing system, though, rather than specifying the `:controller => "assets", :action => "new", ...` hash.

You might consider using CSS to make the `<a>` from your `<%= link_to ... %>` look nice, rather than replacing it with an awkward button.

- button_to: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to
- better routing: [enter link description here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)